# Shell script to print value of variable recursively

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
A="X"
X="Y"
B=${$A}
echo $B # expecting output to be 'Y'
```

Actual output seen : line 4: ${$A}: bad substitution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called parameter indirection:

You can use `${!nameref}` to treat the value of `nameref` as a parameter:

```
A="X"
X="Y"
B=${!A}
echo "$B"
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html for more info on parameter expansion

Comment: Thanks @Andreas Louv. 
The solution you provided works. But, when i implement the same with below example, it fails. 

```
artifact-name="node-script" 
node-script=2021111012 
artifact-version=${!artifact-name} 
echo "${artifact-version}" 
```

Error: 
```
script.sh: line 1: artifact-name=node-script: command not found 
script.sh: line 2: node-script=2021111012: command not found 
script.sh: line 3: artifact-version=name: command not found 
```

Looks like it is not parsing the `-` symbol in variable name/value.

Comment: Yes `-` is invalid as parameter names